# How can a touchdown catch be made when the receiver lands outside the End Zone?

Tags: nfl, scoring

Why  was [this catch by Chris Hogan](http://www.nfl.com/videos/nfl-game-highlights/0ap3000000857231/Chris-Hogan-hauls-in-6-yard-touchdown-with-Vernon-Hargreaves-all-over-him) for the Patriots against the Buccaneers, on October 5th 2017, a touchdown, as he caught the ball in the air and landed outside of the End Zone? I thought the catching player had to touch down with both feet?

Comment: I added a link to the official Highlight, which should be permanent. If it gets deleted, and we are in 2020, it was the patriots only touchdown of the night Q2 3:42

Answer (score 3):

From a *[NFL Rulebook Rule 11: Scoring](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2017-nfl-rulebook/#rule11)*

> SECTION 2, ARTICLE 1. TOUCHDOWN PLAYS
>
> A touchdown is scored when:
>
> **2**. a ball in possession of an airborne runner is on, above, or behind the plane of the goal line, and some part of the ball passed over or inside the pylon
>
> **Note 1**: The ball is automatically dead when it is in legal possession of a player and is on, above, or behind the opponent’s goal line.

And from *[NFL Rulebook Rule 3: Definitions](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2017-nfl-rulebook/#article-7.-player-possession)*

> SECTION 2,  ARTICLE 7. PLAYER POSSESSION
>
> **Item 1**. Player in Possession. A player is in possession when he is inbounds and has a firm grip and control of the ball with his hands or arms.
>
> **Note 3**: If a player has control of the ball, a slight movement of the ball will not be considered loss of possession. He must lose control of the ball in order to rule that there has been a loss of possession.

All these rules come into play for the case when the receiver lands outside the End Zone.

Look at this image, (taken from the linked video)

[image: caught]

Which shows Chris Hogan is airborne inside the goal line, and ball is also inside the pylon which makes it a touchdown.

And from linked note, ball becomes dead in a legal possession of a player above the opponent’s goal line. He also has a firm grip and control of the ball which makes it a legal possession. So, it doesn't matter where he lands (as long as he is in bounds), that's why the catch is legal touchdown.