# Is it a touchdown if a receiver flips over the end line and lands out of bounds?

Tags: american-football, scoring

In the Bengals-Ravens game on 2023-11-16, the Ravens second touchdown was scored when a a receiver ran down field, flipped before the endzone and landed with his left foot out of bounds. Was the ruling of a touchdown correct, and if so why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a touchdown catch be made when the receiver lands outside the End Zone?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17087/how-can-a-touchdown-catch-be-made-when-the-receiver-lands-outside-the-end-zone) - while it's not _quite_ the same scenario, it's the same rule (2.1.2).

Comment: There's no need to the answer into the question - instead please accept (the check mark to the left) of the answer you find most useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://x.com/Ravens/status/1725340444907782170?s=20

The rule states that the player needs to have possession of the ball and that the ball be inside/over (in the air) the zone. If the player jumps over an opponent, or a line, but puts the ball (think: one handed) over the zone, even when falling or being pushed outside, he had possession of the ball in the zone, so it's a clear TD.

From [NFL - scoring plays](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-video-rulebook/scoring-plays/):

> SECTION 2 - TOUCHDOWN
> ARTICLE 1. TOUCHDOWN PLAYS
>
> A touchdown is scored when:
>
> 1. the ball is on, above, or behind the plane of the opponents’ goal line (extended) and is in possession of a runner who has advanced from the field of play into the end zone
> 2. a ball in possession of an airborne runner is on, above, or behind the plane of the goal line, and some part of the ball passed over or inside the pylon
> 3. a ball in player possession touches the pylon, provided that, after contact by an opponent, no part of the player’s body, except his hands or feet, struck the ground before the ball touched the pylon
> 4. any player who is legally inbounds catches or recovers a loose ball (3-2-4) that is on, above, or behind the opponent’s goal line
> 5. the Referee awards a touchdown to a team that has been denied one by a palpably unfair act

Comment: It's interesting that in Rugby you need to touch the ball down to the ground but it's not called a touchdown whereas in football it's called a touchdown but you don't actually need to touch the ball to the ground.